# C++ having a glitch?

Tags: c++

So I was working on this [Codeforces problem](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/218/B) and I wrote a program to solve it, but it wasn't printing the right answer so I decided to try debugging it. Attached below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int maxof(int a[], int m)
{
  int x = a[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
    if (x < a[i])
      x = a[i];
  return x;
}

int maxind(int a[], int m)
{
  int x = maxof(a,m);
  int n = 0;
  while (a[n] != x)
    n++;
  return n;
}

...

int maxcost(int a[], int n, int m)
{
  int x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    /*
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
      cout << a[j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    */
    x += maxof(a,m);
    a[maxind(a,m)]--;
  }
  return x;
}

...

int main()
{
  int n,m;
  cin >> n >> m;
  int a[m];
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    cin >> a[i];
  /*
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    cout << a[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
  */
  cout << maxcost(a,n,m) << " " << mincost(a,n,m);
}
```

So if I take out the /* */ blocks and run the program with the input

```
4 3
2 1 1
```

It SHOULD print out:

```
2 1 1
2 1 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
0 0 1
0 0 0
5 5
```

But it's printing out:

```
2 1 1 
2 -3 1 
1 -3 1 
0 -3 1 
0 -3 0 
4 4
```

Where did this random -3 come from, and how do I fix this?

Comment: how did you debug it? using debugger to step over code?

Comment: Most probably a problem with your implementation, not a compiler _'glitch'_ ...

Comment: I just tried putting the cout statements at places to try to see where the problem is. Now I found the problem, but I don't know why that's happening.

Comment: It takes the input of `2 1 1` perfectly fine, but as soon as I call the `maxcost` method it randomly changes the entries to `2 -3 1`.

Comment: Use a debugger and single step!

Comment: I'm just asking to learn, is it possible in c++ to do this : `int a[m]` ?? It is in the third line in the main function.

Comment: @T-D Not really, since `m` here is not a compile-time constant. It's an extension in g++ (and clang++), borrowed from C (>= C99).

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/UDDS2x) after modifying your code to the point where it actually compiles. The problem must lie in the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evaluation order is undefined in your case between `maxcost` and `mincost`

`maxcost` modify `a`, so I assume that `mincost` does the same.

In your case `mincost` is computed first, so `maxcost` get a modified `a` as input.

Clone `a` before calling or inside `maxValueCost` (same apply to `minValueCost`).
or make sure that `maxcost` and `mincost` don't change `a`.

Comment: Oh it is? I had no idea. So I'm guessing the way to solve this problem is to clone the `a` array?

Comment: You may clone `a`, or find an algorithm which don't change `a`. You may use `std::vector`.

Comment: @2012ssohn Arrays in arguments implicitly become pointers. So `a[_x_]` inside those functions is not a copy of `a` but the actual `a`. You could try `std::array`, it shouldn't but it could also be converted into pointer, I am not sure.

Comment: @Jarod42: Apparently, he wants to run both functions of the original input array. This means that your approach will not work properly either, since the first `maxcost` call will destroy the original array content.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[maxind(a,m)]--;
```

Your problem lies in this line. The only place you decrement any value in the code is here.

Set a breakpoint here and you will see what is going on.